# java - Getting all content of a xml node as string

Tags: java, xml

I am using this code to parsing xml

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(data));
    Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Now I want to get all content from a xml node.
Like from this xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<type>
  <human>                     
    <Name>John Smith</Name>              
    <Address>1/3A South Garden</Address>    
  </human>
</type>
```

So if want to get all content of `<human>` as text.

> ```
> <Name>John Smith</Name>
> <Address>1/3A South Garden</Address>
> ```

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
private String nodeToString(Node node) {
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  try {
    Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
  } catch (TransformerException te) {
    System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
  }
  return sw.toString();
}
```

Comment: The dzone link posted above by @ObenSonne looks taken down (returns a 410 for me), so thanks for posting the code here!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're doing? I have the same question but this answer doesn't work: (following OP example) my resulting String always contains the `<human>` start and end tags and I need it without.

Comment: Worked for me. I was not able to print DOM Nodes as their tags appear in the xml. This function allowed me to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Transformer it's also possible to use [LSSerializer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.xml/org/w3c/dom/ls/LSSerializer.html). For large nodes this serializer is faster.

Example:

```
    public static String convertNodeToString(Node node) {

        DOMImplementationLS lsImpl = (DOMImplementationLS)node.getOwnerDocument().getImplementation().getFeature("LS", "3.0");
        LSSerializer lsSerializer = lsImpl.createLSSerializer();

        DOMConfiguration config = lsSerializer.getDomConfig();
        config.setParameter("xml-declaration", Boolean.FALSE);

        return lsSerializer.writeToString(node);

   }
```