# How to get XML content as a String

Tags: java, xml, dom

```
<root>
<h id="1">
    <d value="1,2,3,4,5"><open>10:00</open><close>23:00</close></d>
    <d value="6"><open>10:00</open><close>2:00</close></d>
    <d value="7"><open>10:00</open><close>21:00</close></d>
</h>
<h id="2">
</h>
</root>
```

Here I have the XML which root has list of `<h>` tagged nodes. Now I need to break these into parts and set it into different variables (add into a map).

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes("utf-8"))));
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("h");
for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++)
{
    Node nNode = nList.item(i);
    System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id") + " " + ?????);        
}
```

what should I call in order to get the value (**String value**) of a `nNode` ?

Here is what Im looking for as the asnwer for the above code once some one fills the ????

```
1 <h id="1"><d value="1,2,3,4,5"><open>10:00</open><close>23:00</close></d><d value="6">open>10:00</open><close>2:00</close></d><d value="7"><open>10:00</open><close>21:00</close></d></h>
2 <h id="2"></h>
```

And i don't mind having  as root element

Comment: I answered [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21661452/2071828) recently about getting `String`s of XML subtrees using XPath - that is proabably the best aproach here too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Node.getTextContent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29) to conveniently get all the text of a node (gets text of children as well).

See [Parsing xml file contents without knowing xml file structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963137/parsing-xml-file-contents-without-knowing-xml-file-structure/21963189#21963189) for a short example.

---

If you're trying to get the `value` attributes of the `d` nodes (I can't actually tell, your question is slightly unclear to me), then it would be different -- for that you would iterate through the children of each `h` node (use `getChildNodes()` or `getFirstChild()` + `getNextSibling()`) then grab their `value` attributes just as you are getting the `id` attribute of the `h` nodes (the above link also shows an example of iterating through child nodes).

Comment: @dinesh707 In that case; does something from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219596/how-to-i-output-org-w3c-dom-element-to-string-format-in-java help? Anver's answer here is also a good option.

Comment: And the problem with  Node.getTextContent() is it just give me text. I even need the XML tags under the main node

Comment: @dinesh707 Yes that is correct; it wasn't clear before your update. Check the link from my previous content and also consider jDom as described in Anver's answer.

Comment: The comment I UP voted did the trick. thank you. But I was hoping for a simpler and direct way. Seems there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried jDom library? http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/XMLOutputter.html

```
 XMLOutputter outp = new XMLOutputter();
 String s = outp.outputString(your_jdom_element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `nNode.toString()` if you are using Node from `javax.xml.soap.Node`.

Comment: Im using import org.w3c.dom.*;

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent%28%29)

but your sample nNode has other nodes, not just text. It seems you need helper method to construct String from child nodes.

Pass your nNode to [nodeToString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534182/java-geting-all-content-of-a-xml-node-as-string)

[XML Node to String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412848/xml-node-to-string-in-java)